# Incorrect KDE Ubuntu Shut down. Only browser was opened after startup

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, shutdown, startup

I faced a problem with my KDE Ubuntu when I emergency shut down it. After startup I got no any ui (No taskbar, no any shortcuts work, cannot open start menu and so on). In other words only black screen even without command prompt. I even cannot open terminal, because no graphical items there. The only thing is opened now in my ubuntu is my Mozilla web browser (Seems like because it was in autostart)- it works fine and I am writing this question from it.

But no other windows are able to open

It seems like, that all ubuntu drivers are perfectly working, because wifi connection is stable, graphical card's driver works well.

I think, that something happened with plasma desktop, but I cannot fix it dirrectly because now I cannot open terminal.

I tried to launch ubuntu In safe mode and repair all dpkg packages - no effect.

Do anybody know how to try to fix KDE neon desktop, for instance, from Life USB, or there could be other causes of this issue?

There is photo of my desktop behavior below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging out and change the distro? I think Ubuntu does not grab KDE.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: @newcat1000 Thank you very much, this is the only way I was able to fix my damaged graphical environtment.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there seems to be multiple problems.
First - the plasma-Desktop:
it seems the system still works and apps can run.
Maybe your have a broken Plasma-config (located in ~/.config).
You can test this by just renaming the folder and restart - you can use the virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2).

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config_bck
```

If you get your Plasma-Desktop back, you're fine (okay, you have to reconfigure the stuff, but hey - i think thats not that bad at all...
Also you can write back the config-files step-by-step from ~/.config_bck to ~/.config)

Second:
The Kernel-Log says, that you have an mask-error with your root-pcie-device.
Did you really restarted the system or did you just done a soft-reboot?
My advice: Unplug your pc - Push the power-button twice, replug and start over. Maybe you have also activated some virtualization-stuff in Bios (Intel VT or AMD-V). Disable it, if you dont need them.

Sry if there is bad grammer... I'm still german :-)

Comment: Of, unfortunatelly after renaming this folder even my browser has disappeared

Comment: Okay, this is not bad at all - It's no more in the autostart - like all other user-related configs...
so you can revert this changes (mv ~/.config_bck ~./config).
can you please try to manually restart the plasma-environment and send the syslog?
You can stop/start the environment using this commands:
#KDE 4*
killall plasma-desktop && kstart plasma-desktop
#KDE 5
killall plasmashell && kstart plasmashell
#KDE 5.1+
kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell

Comment: It prompts to me that nor plasmshell and plasmadesktop processes were found (I dont know the version of my kde so I tried both). Moreover it is impossible now to read the syslog, becaise it full of pcie error logs. I suspect this is because my nvidea driver issues.

Comment: Okay.. you can try to filter-out the plasma-entrys using following command:
cat /var/log/syslog | grep "plasma"

Comment: Also you should try to start the os without power-management (grub-command: nomodeset) and see, if this will avoid the pcie-error...

Comment: Hey yeah, I just installed another graphical environtment and now everything works. Unfortunatelly I cannot apply your answer, however in terms to appreciate your help, i will vote it up, because it contains some usefull information for other users. Anyway, thank you very much.